# Why is my circle bouncing off straight surface at an angle?

Tags: javascript, physics, matter.js

I have a ball and two straight vertical surfaces in my world.

When I apply a force to the ball I expect it to stay in a straight line, however it appears to bounce off at an angle.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvjvvzeL/11/

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        Render = Matter.Render,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
        Body = Matter.Body,
        Vector = Matter.Vector,
        Events = Matter.Events;

    // create an engine
    var engine = Engine.create();

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    engine.world.gravity.y = 0; // gravity not needed in this app

    // create a renderer
    var render = Render.create({
        element: document.body,
        canvas: canvas,
        engine: engine,
        options: {wireframes: true}
    });

    var ball_0 = Bodies.circle(100, 150, 11, {
        density: 0.04,
        frictionAir: 0.06,
        restitution: 0.8,
        friction: 0.3
    });

    var cushion_left = Bodies.rectangle(34, 160, 100, 208, { isStatic: true });
    var cushion_right = Bodies.rectangle(492, 160, 100, 208, { isStatic: true });

    // add all of the bodies to the world
    World.add(engine.world, [cushion_left, cushion_right, ball_0]);

    render.options.height = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
    Engine.run(engine);
    Render.run(render);

    Body.applyForce(ball_0, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0.5, y: 0 });
```

Comment: Turning off the friction on the ball fixes it.

Comment: Does the ball have a spin to it?

Comment: no spin i am trying to simulate a pool ball, i wanted friction between the cloth and the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too familiar with MatterJS, but it seems like the ball has angular rotation applied by default. I think this only affects a closed system like the one you've built.

Maybe you'll want it on in the long run, but for now you can set `intertia : Infinity`

```
var ball_0 = Bodies.circle(100, 150, 11, {
    density: 0.04,
    frictionAir: 0.06,
    restitution: 0.8,
    friction: 0.3,
    inertia : Infinity
});
```

But now you also have to apply slightly more force to get the ball to touch the wall. I just turned it up to .6

```
Body.applyForce(ball_0, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: .6, y: 0 });
```

Comment: Curse you for leaving the leading zero off the .6! :P

Comment: intertia vs inertia

Comment: it still bounces off at a weird angle with intertia set to infinity - https://jsfiddle.net/zvjvvzeL/22/

Comment: My bad. I spelled inertia wrong in my example and you seemed to have copied it over.